# Changing decimal separator from comma to period for scale bars in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, decimal-points

How can I change the decimal separator from comma to period for scale bars in ArcGIS Pro? There is no option in the symbology if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This is only possible in the Windows settings in the regional and language settings section